# Is there a way to simplify this summation?

Tags: calculus, summation

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(x^n)(p^n)}{n!}$$

Not sure how to simplify this further, any help would be appreciated

Comment: You could combine: $(x^n)(p^n) = (xp)^n$.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that $p\in\Bbb R$ is some constant. Notice that $(x^n)(p^n)=(xp)^n$. Hence, we have that the series is equivalent to the following:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(xp)^n}{n!}$$
Recall that $$e^a=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a^n}{n!}$$ for any $a\in\Bbb R$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: use the $e^t = 1+t+\dfrac{t^2}{2!}+\cdots$, $t = xp$.